# Have I carefully nurtured a blade of grass?

Tags: identification

I'm a first-time vegetable grower, and planted a lot of pepper seeds, both hot and normal. After some time, a few began to make shoots, so I transplanted them to a larger pot. 
One of them was different, and I thought it was just a chilli plant. After some weeks, it's become almost undeniable, but I just want to make sure. Please could you look at this photo and confirm: is this grass? I'd hate to uproot a growing plant even more than I'd hate to have been carefully tending a blade of grass.

[image: Unrecognized plant]

Comment: Grass or a cereal of some sort, either way, not a pepper...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speaking from my experience (been growing peppers for three years), this is certainly not a pepper plant.

Probably you are indeed growing some grass, but I can't say which species that is ;-)